# How to configure Postgresql (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql in ubuntu but I am unclear how to start or configure it for a local server (apache)

I tried typing (at the terminal prompt)

```
psql
```

but I am getting this error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I'm used to mysql where you can just type

```
mysql -u username -p password
```

I also just tried re-installing postgresql, this is my error message:

```
Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.3-0ubuntu0.11.10) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                       * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2012-03-05 10:57:06 EST LOG:  invalid connection type "localhost"
2012-03-05 10:57:06 EST CONTEXT:  line 76 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf"
2012-03-05 10:57:06 EST LOG:  invalid connection type "METHOD"
2012-03-05 10:57:06 EST CONTEXT:  line 100 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf"
2012-03-05 10:57:06 EST FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-9.1; however:
  Package postgresql-9.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Is PostgreSQL running?

Comment: I just tried to start it using : postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data and I get the message No command 'postgres' found, did you mean:

Comment: That's not how you start it.  Do you have `root` or `sudo` access to run something as user `postgres`?

Answer (score 2):

Normally before you go check anything else I'd check whether or not the PostgreSQL is even running:

```
ps -fu postgres
```

If it is running you will need to edit `/etc/postgres/postres.conf`, `/etc/postgres/pg_hba.conf` to get this configured properly.

You can see [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime-config.html) for more details.

If the server is not running the you might have to try and start it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-<version> restart
```

If the problem continues then I'd start checking logs to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried running the first command I got this message:

Comment: UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD

Comment: @nicole That means that the database engine is not running.  You will have to start it and if it doesn't start configure it and then start it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PostgreSQL has stopped so must start it. Try the below command for starting the PostgreSQL:

To check the status:

> sudo /etc/init.d/postgres status

To start:

> sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start